# Future question

Tags: future-tense

"When will the first lesson take place?"

Or

"When the first lesson will take place?"

I think that the first option is correct because we put 'will' before the subject, am I right?

Comment: The second example is not a question nor a complete sentence. It could form part of a sentence as in: **When the first lesson will take place is not yet decided** - meaning that the time or date is not yet decided. This is a statement rather than a question.

Comment: Please review interrogative question forms. This can easily be found on the internet. There are basic rules about the position of helping verbs. They are always in the same place.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct.

Questions are formed with inversion. But you’re right, “will” and “take place” are separated.

> **When** *will* **the lesson** take place?
>
> **The lesson** *will* take place **tomorrow**.

Answer (score 0):

In English language, if you are to ask a question, you use the word before the subject as in the case of first sentence that you have mentioned. 
The second sentence is in indirect speech. 
For example, I ask him when the first lesson will take place.